# How to organize work pool based on PostgreSQL table?

Tags: performance, postgresql, parallel-processing, race-condition

Suppose I have a big table in PostgreSQL (more than 500Gb) - work pool. Also I have a number of worker processes, getting works from work pool.
What is the most efficient way to release manager, that would return next string from the
'work pool' table as response to workers requests. May be some kind of cursor, iterator or whatever?

*UPD* I have forgotten one key thing - table is constant. No INSERT or UPDATE operations are allowed. We just reading from it.

Comment: Your question is too general. Post whatever you have tried.

Comment: @lanzz My decision is external - release simple deamon (libpq), witch would select data to the internal buffer and use bsd-sockets (udp) to communicate with workers.

Comment: @hoxnox Then post an answer explaining that (and why) and accept your own answer. That way nobody will spend time looking into a question that's resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I whanted to be redirected to [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-declare.html) and [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-fetch.html). Thanks to http://habrahabr.ru/qa/22030/, user ToSHiC and strib.

Answer (score 2):

[PGQ](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PGQ_Tutorial) may be or may not be suitable for the problem. It covers similar problem areas, so have a look.